# [C++]This as default parameter

Tags: c++, list, parameters, this

I want to write a recursive function that gives me the lenght of a list.
To make it recursive, i use this pointer as default parameter in the declaration of the function in the List class header. But the compiler gives me an error...
This is the code:

```
//Header file
#include "Nodo.h"

template < class Tipo >

class Lista
{

    private:
        Nodo< Tipo >* Prox; 

    public:
        Lista();

        bool ListaVuota();

        int DimensioneLista(Lista<Tipo>* = this);

        void InserisciInCoda(Tipo);

};

//CPP file

template< class Tipo >

int Lista< Tipo >::DimensioneLista(Lista< Tipo >* lista)

{

    if(lista->ListaVuota())
        return 0;
    else
        return 1+DimensioneLista(lista);

}
```

Comment: What error and in what line?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, `this` can only be used within functions.

The simplest change would be to use `NULL` as your default value instead, then check for `NULL` in your function, and use `this` instead

Comment: Simpler still, an overload, so there's no need for a runtime check: `int DimensioneLista() {return DimensioneLista(this);}`

Comment: @MikeSeymour You might want to make this a separate answer.